# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: magento-1.9, error, javascript, frontend-error

I see this error, related to this line:

```
var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Cerca nell\\'intero negozio...');
```

I have to modify "Cerca nell\", but I don't find the file that I should modify. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You should modify following way

```
var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Cerca nell\'intero negozio...');
```

Following file :

app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml

OR

app/design/frontend/[YourPackage]/[YourTheme]/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml

Comment: there isn't "cerca nell\\'" in these files.

Comment: It was a translation issue. Solved.